# curl --cacert vs python requests verify

Tags: python, ssl, curl, python-requests, ca

I'm trying to connect to a website that uses unofficial CA via https. For some reason it works with curl but not with python requests.

See the example below

```py
Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 30 2019, 11:47:54) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.9.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import requests 

In [2]: requests.__version__ 
Out[2]: '2.22.0'

In [3]: cert = "..." 

In [4]: url = "..." 

In [5]: !curl --cacert {cert} {url} 
{"status":200}

In [6]: requests.get(url,verify=cert) 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSLCertVerificationError Traceback (most recent call last)
...
SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='...', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: ... (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError Traceback (most recent call last)
...

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='...', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: ... (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is it behaving differently?

--EDIT--

curl is using this cert for sure, without it curl fails

```py
In [9]: !curl {url}                                                                                                                                                                                                
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

...

In [10]:
```

Comment: does it work with verify=False?

Comment: What is the content of the cert file? Is it a root CA or only an intermediate CA? Or is it a self-signed certificate which does not have the CA flag set in basic constraints?

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich it's an intermediate CA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...  it's an intermediate CA

Having only the intermediate CA in the trust store is not sufficient for validation of the certificate, at least not with the current versions of Python. This feature would require the use of the OpenSSL flag `X509_V_FLAG_PARTIAL_CHAIN` for verification, which is [neither currently exposed by Python](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/20463) nor set by default.

Contrary to this curl [sets this flag by default](https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/4655) in newer versions and thus works.

Comment: There are 2 ways to fix this, you can't use 2 files in python, but you can concatenate Root and Sub CA into 1 file. Another way is for the server to show the whole chain.

Comment: @Kazz: The first option to put the full chain including the root certificate into the CA store is possible. The second option of the server sending the full chain including the root CA is not. The client will ignore any root CA sent by the server because it expects the root of the trust chain to be already trusted locally.